# Изменение настройки wait_timeout в MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Хочу изменить настройки MySQL, а именно, `wait_timeout`. Дописываю в файл `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` соответствующую строку, перегружаю сервер, но настройки не применяются и остается старое значение. Еще файлов с настройками, перекрывающих данный файл, я не нашел в системе. Подскажите, что еще можно сделать или почему не происходит изменения параметра?

Comment: А в какой секции ([clients], [mysqld]) изменяете значение директивы `wait_timeout` и как потом проверяете изменение директивы?

Comment: @cheops менял в [mysqld]. Проверял командой SHOW VARIABLES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

согласно [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout):

> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to mysql_real_connect())

т.е., для сессии интерактивного клиента (в котором вы проверяете значение) в качестве сессионного значения для `wait_timeout` берётся значение не глобальной переменной `wait_timeout`, а глобальной переменной  `interactive_timeout`.

т.о., чтобы изменить `wait_timeout` для **интерактивного** клиента, измените глобальное значение `interactive_timeout`.

---

а для того, чтобы проверить значение этой перменной для **неитерактивных** клиентов с помощью того же самого клиента, выполните запрос **неинтерактивно**, примерно так:

```
$ echo 'show variables like "wait_timeout"' | mysql
```

---

ещё раз, многословнее:

- чтобы установить сессионное значение `wait_timeout` для **интерактивных** сессий, меняйте глобальную переменную `interactive_timeout`
- чтобы установить сессионное значение `wait_timeout` для **неинтерактивных** сессий, меняйте глобальную переменную `wait_timeout`

Comment: Т.е. я устанавливаю в my.cnf новое значение не для wait_timeout, а для interactive_timeout. Перегружаю сервер. Захожу под в консоль MySQL и при помощи SHOW VARIABLES вижу, что обе переменных (и wait_timeout и interactive_timeout) приняли новое одинаковое значение. Выхожу из консоли ввода команд мускула и ввожу неинтерактивно `$ echo 'show variables like...` и вижу старое неизменное значение для wait_timeout и новое для interactive_timeout. Вопрос... А какое из них будет действовать в действительности при подключении клиента (с++) к базе данных? Через сколько ждать обрыва?

Comment: Установив таким образом небольшие значения для interactive_timeout наблюдаю, что соединение все равно остается активным. Т.е. interactive_timeout не действует, а действует wait_timeout (а оно по умолчанию составляет 8 часов).

Comment: клиент может открыть неинтерактивное соединение, а может интерактивное (см. цитату по поводу названия параметра и функции). при неинтерактивном соединении значение для **сессионного** `wait_timeout` берётся из **глобального** `wait_timeout`. а при интерактивном соединении значение для **сессионного** `wait_timeout` берётся из **глобального** `interactive_timeout`.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Т.е. ответом на мой поставленный вопрос по сути является: "изменить значение wait_timeout невозможно".

Comment: *Установив таким образом небольшие значения для interactive_timeout наблюдаю, что соединение все равно остается активным* — а клиента вы точно запускали с опцией `--skip-reconnect`? ну, чтоб он не переподключался автоматически при потере соединения.

Comment: Клиенту не даются никакие дополнительные опции. Насколько я читал документацию (да и сталкивался в реальности), то автоматического переподключения не произойдет (если не выставлен в опциях изначально запрос на автопереподключение). Собственно, и причиной вопроса является именно тот момент, что будучи неактивным длительное время (больше wait_timeout), он не может в последствие переподключиться. Для этого необходима установка соответствующих опций (и перекомпиляция). По этому пути, скорее всего, и придется идти ввиду невозможности изменения wait_timeout.

Comment: @Softinaria, установите `interactive_timeout` в единицу (1 секунда), выполните *restart* (не *reload*) для *mysqld*. запустите `$ mysql --skip-reconnect`. подождите 1 секунду и введите любой sql-запрос (например, `show variables`). вы получили ошибку вроде *ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away*? значит, соединение было разорвано сервером по истечении указанного таймаута. а если у вас есть вопросы по поводу поведения написанного вами клиента, то задавайте их с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: У меня нет вопросов по поведению написанного мной клиента. Я знаю причину того, что он не может подключиться к базе данных спустя определенное время. Я не просто знаю - я уверен в этом. Это исправляется изменением значения wait_timeout. Вопрос был в том, как ее изменить. Я могу изменить ее значение на время текущей сессии, но после рубута всего сервака, все вернется на круги своя. А меня это не устраивает. Вопрос остался тем же. И то что я в комментах оговорился о его причине - не влияет ни на что.

Comment: вы всё изменяли верно. проверить текущее значение можно, выполнив `echo 'show variables like "wait_timeout"' | mysql`. повторю рекомендацию: если у вас есть вопросы по поводу поведения написанного вами клиента, то задавайте их, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос». на текущий же вопрос вам дан (очень надеюсь) исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Хорошо... Исходим из того, что значение wait_timeout не меняется напрямую. Его можно изменить только посредством interactive_timeout. При этом, для неинтерактивного клиента получается так, что оно не меняется в принципе. А для интерактивного клиента используется значение interactive_timeout. Получается, что ответом на вопрос является, то, что никак изменить значение wait_timeout невозможно. И единственный выход - менять настройки клиента. Ваш ответ не является таковым. Но за оказанную поддержку и помощь благодарен (upvote)

Comment: *значение wait_timeout не меняется напрямую. Его можно изменить только посредством interactive_timeout.* — клиент сам указывает при подключении — интерактивный он или нет. в зависимости от этого таймаут подключения для сессии выбирается сервером либо из переменной `wait_timeout`, либо из переменной `interactive_timeout`. что никак не препятствует тому, чтобы клиент после подключения сам изменил сессионное значение `wait_timeout` с помощью соответствующего sql-запроса.